# Unable to generate Allue report in Jenkins RobotFramework

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework, allure

i'm trying to generate the allure report in jenkins, tried all configurations but still unable to generate the alure report in robot framework.

Added the allure add-in in jenkins,

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Allure report]

- **Output**

  ====== WebDriver manager ======
  Getting latest mozilla release info for v0.34.0
  Trying to download new driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.34.0/geckodriver-v0.34.0-win64.zip
  Driver has been saved in cache [C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\win64\v0.34.0]

  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\InvolvemeRobotFramework\TestCases\Workspaces>exit 0
  [RobotFrameworkInvolveme_Delete] $ C:\Test\allure-2.16.1\bin\allure.bat generate -c -o C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\RobotFrameworkInvolveme_Delete\allure-report
  allure-results does not exist
  Report successfully generated to C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\RobotFrameworkInvolveme_Delete\allure-report
  Allure report was successfully generated.
  Creating artifact for the build.
  Artifact was added to the build.
  Finished: SUCCESS

Can someone Please help me